# AngularJS - Confirm password validation is working only if Password field is valid

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-messages

Please check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Ayyappu/1eh28db6/

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && vm.login()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.password.$invalid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}" />
            <div ng-messages="form.$submitted && form.password.$error" class="help-block">
                <div ng-message="required">Password is required</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid format</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.confirmPassword.$invalid }">
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.confirmPassword" required compare-to="vm.password" />
            <div ng-messages="form.$submitted && form.confirmPassword.$error" class="help-block">
                <div ng-message="required">Confirm Password is required</div>
                <div ng-message="compareTo">Passwords don't match</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button ng-disabled="vm.loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>                        
    </form>
</body>


var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);

app.directive("compareTo", function() {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
          return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
        };

        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
          ngModel.$validate();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**Validations in the first textbox (Password)**

- Mandatory
- The password must contain at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case, 1 number, 1 special character and its length should be between 8 and 15

**Validations in the second textbox (Confirm Password)**

- Mandatory
- It should match with the first textbox (Password)

**Issue:**

Mandatory validation is working fine in both the textboxes. Password policy is also working fine in the first textbox (Password). However, the password match validation in the second textbox (Confirm Password) is working only if the first textbox (Password) passes validation.

e.g., 'Ab1!efgh' is a valid password. If you enter this in both the textboxes, there are no validation errors in the form. However, if you enter just 'a' in the first textbox (Password) and the second textbox (Confirm Password), then there is an error in the second textbox (Confirm Password) saying that the passwords don't match. This clearly shows that 'Confirm password validation is working only if Password field is valid'

I want the password match validation in the second textbox (Confirm Password) to work even if the password you enter in the first textbox (Password) is invalid.

Please help.

Comment: `However, the password match validation in the second textbox (Confirm Password) is working only if the first textbox (Password) passes validation.`... Nope, I checked the jsfiddle and it is behaving as expected. Did I miss something? If you click submit and type something in the second input, the text changes from `Confirm Password is required` to `Passwords don't match` even when the first input is not valid.

Comment: Please enter just 'a' in both the textboxes and submit. The validation in the first texbox should be 'Invalid Format' and the second textbox should not have any error. However, second textbox shows 'Passwords don't match'.

Comment: So, what's the expected behavior? If the first input is invalid, do not validate the passwords matching ( validate that passwords match when the first checkbox is a valid password) ??

Comment: I want password match to work irrespective of the password validity.

Comment: Is this (https://jsfiddle.net/dgycxszx/) the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `vm.password` won't update by `ng-model` if the `pattern` fails.

you have to use `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` to allow value change if pattern valid fails.

see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/htnqLuwWevMXnvBK7JM9?p=preview)